# Java: unzip 7-zip archive

Tags: java, android, archive, tar, 7zip

How can I unzip 7-zip and tar archives in Java? Without cmd commands.

I tried to use Zip4j but it can unzip only Zip. And I need 7z and tar.

What library (not heavy) can I use? Or how can it be done with native Java-library?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try Googling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream ?

Comment: If you need an example let me know.

Comment: yea, give me example, please